# Sharing on Linkedin using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, socialshare

I would like to create a custom activity controller with `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `Google+`, `Linkedin` and `Pinterest` share options.

[GooglePlusShareActivity](https://github.com/stoulouse/PinterestShareActivity/blob/master/LICENSE) and [PinterestShareActivity](https://github.com/stoulouse/PinterestShareActivity) are what I have found for `Google+` and `Pinterest`.

Is there any customized implementation of `Linkedin` for this purpose?

Comment: u must have these all apps in ur iphone

Comment: @muku - not necessarily for Google+.

Comment: @technophyle did you ever get this working? i found the one for google plus too and it's great! did you find anything as simple for linkedin?

Comment: @skinsfan00atg unfortunately no. I'm still struggling to find one. did you implement google plus custom activity controller?

Comment: @technophyle ok, i dont understand why its so hard to get such a simple thing done, i saw linkedin has updated some documentation since last i looked: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin     i got the google plus one working in a few hours, thats what's frustrating about linkedin. let me know if you need help on that one

Comment: looks like that link is the whole brand new SDK just released yesterday! so hopefully thats the answer to our problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn has finally released an iOS SDK: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin,  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk

Looks pretty thorough so hopefully this makes it easy!

Only issue i see so far is this: "Remember that the Mobile SDK-enabled applications require the official LinkedIn iOS app to be installed on the device to function properly". Not sure if that means just to share, the user needs the app because that would be a little frustrating. In iOS 8, if the user has the app installed, there's a built-in extension already. So the SDK would solve iOS 7 (be pretty small when 9 comes out) and more complicated scenarios than just sharing i suppose

Answer (score 1):

you can implement linkedin sharing in ios using following steps :

Integration of Linkedin Api in IOS
The LinkedIn platform provides you the ability to register and sign-in to your application or website with their LinkedIn identity and also allow user to connect their LinkedIn account to your application, in order to easily publish their activities to their linkedIn account.

Get started to Integrate Linkedin Api in iOS App :
1.) Create a Project in your xcode using “Empty Application” in your Xcode and note their bundle id which will be needed when you register your app on Linkedin Website.

2.) Create a UIViewController class with their xib ( like LoginLinkedInViewController ) and set it as a rootViewController of Window in AppDelegate class.

3.) First of all,you have to register your app here https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer by using your current linked account or create a new one linkedin account.

4.) After completion of registation of your app on Linkedin website, you will get a API Key,Secret Key ,OAuth User Token and OAuth User Secret.

Here ,we are a using a Library OAutho for integrating with user linkedin account and after login User can post a status to their linkedin account.

5.) First of all ,you have to download Library from here and unzip it. Now you have to drag and drop OAuthLoginView,ASIHTTP and OAuthStarterKit folder in Project Navigator of Xcode.

6.) For Removing Linking error in xcode ,you have to add -all_load,-ObjC and -lc++ flag as shown

7.) Expand “Link Binaries with Libraries”. Select the “+” button, and add these frameworks SystemConfiguration.framework ,CFNetwork.framework and libz.dylib.

Now enter the code to share on linkedin 
you will get required code here [Linkedin Share in ios](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Linkedin-Integration-in-Native-iOS)